# How to only write NEW, unique data to csv file after appending original csv - Python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm having my script append a csv file (work.csv) of links previously recorded, and writing the new data into that same csv.  Then I need to remove any duplicates from that list, I've gotten that down.  Where I'm struggling is the next step.  After running my NEW data, against my OLD data to remove duplicates, how would I write only the unique NEW data to a new csv. (work2.csv)

Note, I've only included code relevant to the question. Thank you in advance for any help/insight/information!!

Here is my code:

```
     from csv import reader, writer
     from more_itertools import unique_everseen


     with open('work.csv', 'a', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:

            
            thewriter = writer(f)
        
            
                
                links = example.com

               

                thewriter.writerow([links])

        with open('work.csv', 'r') as f, open('work2.csv', 'w') as out_file:
            out_file.writelines(unique_everseen(f))
```

Comment: read all data to Python, select what you need, display it to see if you selected correct data, and later write it. Simply: use `print()` to debug your code.

Comment: maybe you should read all old data, and check if you have this link on list and write link only if link doesn't exists in old data. This way you don't have to check duplicates.

Comment: Removing duplicates isn't the problem for me, the issue comes after that.  I have a file, that contains all my previously recorded links.  My script collects NEW links and adds them to that same file. Then I remove duplicates so im not saving any link twice.  Then my script writes all the data unique data to a second csv file.  My issue is I only want my script to write NEW unique data to the second csv file.

Comment: I only want my second csv. file to contain links that I just collected, that are not in the first csv file.

Comment: I would do all in different way. You first write new data to old data and later you read all data and you don't know which one are new. But I would first read old data (and keep in separated list) and I would check if new data exist in old data and write it to new file

Comment: if you really have to first write all to one file and later search unique values then you should add column with some information to recognize new items - i.e. date, or the same number for all new values. But this way `unique_everseen` may not work because. I think it can be much simpler if you will keep old data and new data in separated list.